# Multiple Foreign Keys in loopback model relation

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

In the loopback model relations section, you can specificity a foreignKey to be referenced in the other model. As far as I know, It will only take one field, but what about I have a composite primary key and want to be referenced in the other model?

Can I do something like?

```
"foreignKey":["id1","id2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the moment and there is discussion on [core loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2080) and related repos (for specific database connectors), so add your +1 (not comment) to mark it as important feature to implement. I am also waiting for this to happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Composite Key in my project in a slight different way, and it works well. Try creating your id in the model to be referenced in this manner:

```
"id": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": true,
    "id1": {
         "type": "string"
         "id": true
     },
    "id2": {
         "type": "string",
         "id": true
     }
}
```

And then reference it in another model like this:

```
"foreignKey": "modelId"
```